# Lazy order by/where evaluation

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

**Edit**

It seems that a pure materialization can be stored as a column on the table and indexed; however, my specific use case (`semver.satisfies`) requires a more general solution:

```
create table Submissions (
    version text
    created_at timestamp
)

create index Submissions_1 on Submissions (created_at)
```

My query would then look like:

```
select * from Submissions
where
    created_at <= '2016-07-12' and
    satisfies(version, '>=1.2.3 <4.5.6')
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

Where I wouldn't be able to practically use the same memoization technique.

**Original**

I have a table storing text data and the dates at which they were created:

```
create table Submissions (
    content text,
    created_at timestamp
);

create index Submissions_1 on Submissions (created_at);
```

Given a checksum and a reference date, I want to get the latest `Submission` where the `content` field matches that checksum:

```
select * from Submissions
where
    created_at <= '2016-07-12' and
    expensive_chksm(content) = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

This works, but it's very slow. What Postgres ends up doing is taking a checksum of every row, and then performing the `order by`:

```
 Limit  (cost=270834.18..270834.18 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1132.898..1132.898 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=270834.18..271561.27 rows=290836 width=32) (actual time=1132.898..1132.898 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Seq Scan on installation  (cost=0.00..269380.00 rows=290836 width=32) (actual time=0.118..1129.961 rows=17305 loops=1)
               Filter: created_at <= '2016-07-12' AND expensive_chksm(content) = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'
               Rows Removed by Filter: 982695
 Planning time: 0.066 ms
 Execution time: 1246.941 ms
```

Without the `order by`, it is a sub-millisecond operation, because Postgres knows that I only want the first result. The only difference is that I want Postgres to start searching from the latest date down.

Ideally, Postgres would:

> 1. filter by `created_at`
> 2. sort by `created_at`, descending
> 3. return the first row where the checksum matches

I've tried to write queries with inline views, but an `explain analyze` shows that it will just be rewritten into what I already had above.

Comment: You could use normal comparison and normal index if you stored it a little more reasonably, like for example bigint `1000002000003` instead of `1.2.3` and `4000005000006` instead of 4.5.6 (major*10^12+minor*10^6+release).

Comment: It's a good idea, but semver is really tricky. I've experimented with several approaches and it seems that what I'm currently trying yields the best performance-accuracy balance. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: May be than use int[] -> [1,2,3] ? It is also good index and better to comparing?

Answer (score 2):

You can create index for both fields together:

```
create index Submissions_1 on Submissions (created_at DESC, expensive_chksm(content));

                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.15..8.16 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using submissions_1 on submissions  (cost=0.15..16.17 rows=2 width=40) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((created_at <= '2016-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((content)::text = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'::text))
 Planning time: 0.414 ms
 Execution time: 0.036 ms
```

It is important to use also DESC in index.

## UPDATED:

For storing and comparing version you can use int[]

```
create table Submissions (
    version int[],
    created_at timestamp
);

INSERT INTO Submissions SELECT ARRAY [ (random() * 10)::int2, (random() * 10)::int2, (random() * 10)::int2], '2016-01-01'::timestamp + ('1 hour')::interval * random() * 10000 FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);

    create index Submissions_1 on Submissions (created_at DESC, version);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from Submissions
where
    created_at <= '2016-07-12'
    AND version <= ARRAY [5,2,3]
    AND version > ARRAY [1,2,3]
order by created_at desc
limit 1;

                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..13.24 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.074..0.075 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using submissions_1 on submissions  (cost=0.42..21355.76 rows=1667 width=40) (actual time=0.073..0.073 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((created_at <= '2016-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (version <= '{5,2,3}'::integer[]) AND (version > '{1,2,3}'::integer[]))
         Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning time: 3.019 ms
 Execution time: 0.100 ms
```

To a_horse_with_no_name comment:
The order of the conditions in the where clause is irrelevant for the index usage. It's better to put the one that can be used for the equality expression first in the index, then the range expression. –

```
BEGIN;

create table Submissions (
    content text,
    created_at timestamp
);


CREATE FUNCTION  expensive_chksm(varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$
SELECT $1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

INSERT INTO Submissions SELECT (random() * 1000000000)::text, '2016-01-01'::timestamp + ('1 hour')::interval * random() * 10000 FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);
INSERT INTO Submissions SELECT '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e', '2016-01-01'::timestamp + ('1 hour')::interval * random() * 10000 FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

    create index Submissions_1 on Submissions (created_at DESC, expensive_chksm(content));
--    create index Submissions_2 on Submissions (expensive_chksm(content), created_at DESC);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from Submissions
where
    created_at <= '2016-07-12' and
    expensive_chksm(content) = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

Using Submission1:

```
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..10.98 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using submissions_1 on submissions  (cost=0.43..19341.43 rows=1833 width=40) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((created_at <= '2016-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((content)::text = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'::text))
 Planning time: 0.257 ms
 Execution time: 0.033 ms
```

Using Submission2:

```
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4482.39..4482.40 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=29.096..29.096 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4482.39..4486.98 rows=1833 width=40) (actual time=29.095..29.095 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on submissions  (cost=67.22..4473.23 rows=1833 width=40) (actual time=15.457..23.683 rows=46419 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (((content)::text = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'::text) AND (created_at <= '2016-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Heap Blocks: exact=936
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on submissions_1  (cost=0.00..66.76 rows=1833 width=0) (actual time=15.284..15.284 rows=46419 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (((content)::text = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'::text) AND (created_at <= '2016-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
 Planning time: 0.583 ms
 Execution time: 29.134 ms
```

PostgreSQL 9.6.1

Comment: Actually it would be better to do the index in reverse order:  
`create index submissions_chksum_created_desc_idx on submissions (expensive_chksm(content), created_at desc);` as the database would always be able to use binary search to find the row.

Comment: No, the order of index must be the same as in query. In another way - index scan will be used bitmap index scan + bitmap heap scan + sort

Comment: The order of the conditions in the `where` clause is irrelevant for the index usage. It's better to put the one that can be used for the equality expression first in the index, then the range expression.

Comment: @RomanTkachuk, yeah, he would need to `order by expensive_chksm(content), created_at desc`, which does not change the order, but convinces Postgres that it can use the index. My idea works even when there are many rows `created_at<=?` and `expensive_chksm(content)=?` is rare or does not exist.

Comment: I can't use a simple array comparison. Semver has weird rules that are extremely difficult to implement with vanilla SQL. It's better to assume that the `satisfies` function is the only source of truth.

Comment: Which type of comparison ? '~>3.1.0' - WHERE version >= ARRAY[3,1,0] AND version[1] = 3 AND . You can just construct where clause. Using indexed is much more faster than without. Can you describe what else comparison type do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub query for the timestamp and ordering part, and later run the chksum outside:

```
select * from (
  select * from submissions where
    created_at <= '2016-07-12' and
    order by created_at desc) as S 
where expensive_chksm(content) = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this just gets rewritten by the query planner to what I had before.

Comment: Also, if there's a way to prevent that from being rewritten, I'd have what I need!

Answer (score 0):

If you are always going to query on `checksum` then an alternative would be to have another column called checksum in the table, e.g.:

```
create table Submissions (
    content text,
    created_at timestamp,
    checksum varchar
);
```

You can then `insert/update` the checksum whenever a row gets `inserted/updated` (or write a `trigger`) that does it for you and query on `checksum` column directly for quick result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your solution does work for simple things like verifying checksums. In my project, I'm using a `semver.satisfies` extension to check against a `version` field given a range, so unfortunately, I can't use the same solution. If you have a better analogy, I'd be happy to update the question!

Comment: Is version field also a part of `Submissions` table?

Comment: My actual table looks like this: `(version text, created_at timestamp)` and my where clause looks like: `created_at <= '2016-07-12' and satisfies(version, '>=4.0.0 <5.0.0')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from Submissions
where created_at = (
  select max(created_at) 
  from Submissions 
  where expensive_chksm(content) = '77ac76dc0d4622ba9aa795acafc05f1e')
```

Comment: it will still need to calculate the chksm on all rows in order to find the max created_at